# Microsoft Graph Get list of groups with display name

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get the group membership of a service principal using client credential flow. I have the following code:

```
var graphServiceClient = new Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient(new Microsoft.Graph.DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
{
     var authResult = await _confidentialClientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();
     requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
}));

var groupMembership = await graphServiceClient.ServicePrincipals[userData.UniqueId].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();
```

This returns:
groupMembership.CurrentPage[0].Id but none of the other properties are filled including the one I am interested in groupMembership.CurrentPage[0].DisplayName

I need to return DisplayName as well as the id, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution was to give the app registration the permission of Group.Read.All and then display name was populated in groupMembership